# Custom Image Widget in with Django

Tags: django, django-widget

I'm trying to build a custom Image Widget in the following manner:

```
class ImageWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):

    template_name = 'widgets/picture.html'

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs=None):

        return {'widget': {
            'name': name,
            'value': value,
        }}

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name).render(context)
        return mark_safe(template)
```

The problem is that *value* contains the file's relative path without including the MEDIA prefix (as a form field would). I don't know how to append or how to access that field in Django 1.8

Here's the *picture.html* file contents just in case:

```
Currently: <img src={{ widget.value }}>
<br>Change: <input id="id_profile_image" name="profile_image" type="file">
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<p>
  <label for="id_profile_image">Profile image:</label> Currently: <img src="profile_images/CSC_00111.jpeg">
  <br>Change: <input id="id_profile_image" name="profile_image" type="file">
</p>
```

I need the *src* attribute value to be */media/profile_images/CSC_00111.jpeg*.

Answer (score 0):

You can add media manually like this

```
def get_context(self, name, value, attrs=None):

        return {'widget': {
            'name': name,
            'value': '/media/' + value,
        }}
```

Comment: Actually it's not `/media/`, as I have a different setting. What if the storage backend is S3? I'll try `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`. Maybe that works.

Comment: Try adding settings.MEDIA_ROOT